# PHP and DOM: getting text from a child node

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to get the text data from a child node of an element using PHP and DOM.

Here is the HTML data I'm having trouble parsing.  I'm trying to obtain the email address.

```
<tr>
<th>Engineer:</th>
<td id="contact_person">Jack Smith &lt<a href='mailto:jsmith100@null.com'>jsmith100@null.com</a>&gt
    <table class='transparent'>
        <tr>
            <td>Work Phone</td>
            <td>(555) 555-5555</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Here is my current code for processing that element:

```
$contact = $dom->getElementById("contact_person")->nodeValue;
```

This is the result I'm getting:

```
Jack Smith Work Phone(555) 555-5555
```

UPDATE:  Removing `&lt` and `&gt` and replacing with a single hyphen between name and email address returns the following:

```
Jack Smith - jsmith100@null.comWork Phone(555) 555-5555
```

This is what I want to get:

```
jsmith100@null.com
```

I tried to get the developer to move the "id=contact_person" to the anchor that holds the email address.  Things work fine when I do that in test, but it is not possible to do in our system.

I'm sure it's apparent, but I'm not really familar with DOM and looking for any guidance...

FINAL UPDATE:  THE FIX:

```
$dom->getElementById("contact_person")->firstChild->nextSibling->nodeValue;
```

Comment: It's very odd that your DOM library is not returning the email address in your first example. Is the result really `Jack Smith Work Phone(555) 555-5555` and not `Jack Smith &ltjsmith100@null.com&gtWork Phone(555) 555-5555`?

Comment: removing the `&lt` and `&gt` and replacing with a single hypen `-` did at least make the email address appear:    `<td id="customer_engineer">Jack Smith - <a href='mailto:jsmith100@null.com'>jsmith100@null.com</a>`  produces the result:  `Jack Smith - jsmith100@null.comWork Phone(555) 555-5555`

Comment: sorry. poor attempt to hide my code.  assume `contact_person` is synonymous with `customer_engineer`.

Answer (score 1):

This is ultimately what fixed the issue:

```
$dom->getElementById("contact_person")->firstChild->nextSibling->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$contact = $dom->getElementById("contact_person")->firstChild->nodeValue;
```

Comment: firstChild->nodeValue; returned "Jack Smith".  lastChild->nodeValue; returned "Work Phone(555)555-5555"

Comment: So it seems like you want childNodes[1]

Comment: Changed to childNodes[1]:  `$dom->getElementById("contact_person")->childNodes[1];`  Got the following Error:  `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array`

Comment: Oops. Try childNodes->item(1). The PHP documentation is here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes

Comment: thanks for the link. changing to  `childNodes->item(1)` continued to error.  Your link led me to experiment...  `$dom->getElementById("contact_person")->firstChild->nextSibling->nodeValue;`  this worked!

Answer (score 0):

It may be more reliable to use an XPath query rather than using `firstChild`, `nextSibling` etc.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query("//*[@id='contact_person']//a[contains(@href,'mailto:')]")->item(0);
if( $node) {
    $email = $node->nodeValue;
}
else {
    $email = "NOT FOUND";
}
```

This will look for any link containing "mailto", regardless of where it is inside `#contact_person`. This means that it no longer relies on precise structure, just the container's ID and the fact that it is a `mailto` link.